# Is better Linq or SQL query for complex calculations and aggregations?

Tags: performance, linq, plsql, report, aggregation

We must create and show at runtime (asp.net mvc) some complex reports from Oracle tables data with millions of records. The reports data must be obtained from groupings and little complex calculations.
So is it better for performance and maintainability of code that do these groupings and calculations via sql query (pl/sql) or via linq?
Thanks for your kindle reply

Comment: This question is a little too broad. _Normally_ I'd say the database is faster at those calculations, but it really depends on your _specific_ requirements, data, hardware etc...And to weigh maintainability against performance (which surely means speed, not memory) makes it even broader. So the best suggestion I can give is: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I agree that this question is way too broad. But for consideration, as things get complex it's a lot easier for someone to produce bad linq, as you have less control over the generated script behind the scenes; one wrong mapping may bring in a whole table across the network just to filter for a couple records (then again, there are cases where this is intended behaviour). Also, if your company is full of DBA's but only a single coder, it may be better to unload everything to stored procedures :)

Comment: I'll throw my hat in: in terms of code understandability, linq might be easier to read and understand. Secondly, if the database implementation changes in the future, you won't have to review all your SQL to make sure it works in the new database implementation. You'll just have to make sure that your linq queries are performant.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it better for performance and maintainability of code that do
>   these groupings and calculations via sql query (pl/sql) or via linq?

It depends on what you mean by `via linq`. If you mean that you fetch the complete table to local memory and then use linq statements to extract the result that you want, then of course SQL statements are faster.

However, if you mean that you use Entity Framework, or something similar, then the answer is not  a easy to give.

If you use Entity Framework (or some clone), your tables will be represented by `IQueryable<...>` instead of `IEnumerable<...>`. An `IQueryable` has an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` represents the query that must be performed. The `Provider` knows which system must execute the query (usually a Database Management System) and how to communicate with this system. When the query must be executed, it is the task of the `Provider` to translate the `Expression` into the language that the system knows (usually something SQL-like) and to execute the SQL-query.

There are two kinds of IQueryable LINQ statements: those that return an `IQueryable<...>` of something, and those that return a `TResult`. The ones that return `IQueryable` only change the `Expression`. They are functions that use deferred execution.

Function that do not return an `IQueryable`, are `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Any()`,   `Max()`, etc. Internally they will call functions that will `GetEnumerator()` (usually via a foreach), which orders the `Provider` to translate the `Expression` and execute the query.

**Back to your question**

So which one is more efficient, entity framework or SQL? Efficiency is not only the time to perform the queries, it is also the development/testing time, for the first version and for future changes in the software.

If you use an entity-framework (-clone), the SQL-queries created from the `Expressions` are pretty efficient, depending on the framework manufacturer. If you look at the code, then sometimes the SQL query is not the optimal one, although you'll have to be a pretty good SQL-programmer to improve most queries.

The big advantage above using Entity Framework and LINQ queries above SQL statements is that development times will be shorter. The syntax of the LINQ statements is checked at compile time, SQL statements at run-time. Development and test periods will be shorter.

It is easy to reuse LINQ statements, while SQL statements almost always have to be written especially for the query you want to execute. LINQ statements can be tested without a database on any sequence of items that represent your tables.

**My Advice**

For most queries you won't notice any difference in execution time between the entity framework query or the SQL query.

If you expect complicated queries and future changes, I'd go for entity framework. With main argument the shorter development time, the better testing possibilities, and the better maintainability.

If you detect some queries where you notice that the execution time is too long, you can always decide to bypass entity framework by executing a SQL query instead of using LINQ.

If you've wrapped your `DbContext` in a proper repository, where you hide the use cases from their implementations, the users of your repository won't notice the difference.